# Get all elements matching an XPath expression in a webbrowser document

Tags: .net, xpath, browser

I have a `WebBrowser` in a .net `Form`, and I am looking for a way to get all the `HTMLElement`s that match a given XPath expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that instead of `WebBrowser`, use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

It lets you download documents from the web and supports XPath natively. I also deals well with badly formed HTML and HTML fragments.

Comment: It will require some implementation changes, but I guess it will have to do. Unless someone has a way of selecting XPath elements in the browser itself.

Comment: @Oded, Hi! is there a way to render HTML in a WebBrowser/whatever and highlight specific nodes (by XPATH or other ways - I'm currently using agility pack as well)?

Comment: @Shimmy - This is _probably_ possible (using CSS selectors and javascript). See [this](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) page, in particular the XPath tool.

Comment: @Oded, I'm looking for a .NET utility to be accessible from C#

Comment: @Shimmy - I am not aware of anything built in. My suggestion was to work within the `WebBrowser` control and injecting CSS/Javascript that does the highlighting.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done! I've used the IHtmlDocument3 & IHtmlElement. this control is really powerful! the only disadvantage is that it's COM and it's debugger support is sucky, but is still great. Thanks for your quick response, that was almost like chatting...